How to define and implement a fixed size "List" in Java?
I want to create an fixed size list in java, according to my searchings & readings from the internet i couldn't find that feature in java, However i want to create a fixed size list with 100 elements, when i want to add a new item it should remove 100th element, then adjust the index like this (99th element becomes the 100th element now(Indexes only)) and then my new element should add to the first index.
How to do such a thing in java?

@teapot418 in my case I need to continue with the List interface, therefore I couldn't use other libraries like CircularFifoQueue I wish I had, but unfortunately I couldn't.

@Andro Use an adapter then - your FixedSizeList implements List implementation internally will delegate to LinkedHashMap (for example) or another appropriate data structure. Pick one from the linked question.

See also: Fixed Size Queue Implementations in Java on Baeldung.com.

Such an implementation would be incompatible with the semantics of the List interface. If you add() an item, the interface says that the new item is at its highest index. If you add the new item to the first index, it's not a List. Besides, what should it do with other operations, such as add(index, item)?

You can have your collection class implement a List and have it delegate to an internal Deque.
Here is the add method:
// Note: This is the only important method to implement
// The rest of the methods delegate to the deque field
@Override
public boolean add(T item) {
    // The first item falls off the deque if it's full
    if (deque.size() == maxSize) {
        deque.removeFirst(); // Remove the oldest element
    }
    return deque.add(item); // Add the new element to the end
}

Complete example
Here are two classes; the FixedSizeDequeRunner which contains a main entry-point, and the FixedSizeDeque collection class.
package org.example.collections;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FixedSizeDequeRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> fixedDeque = new FixedSizeDeque<>(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            fixedDeque.add("Item " + i);
        }

        int i = 0;
        for (String item : fixedDeque) {
            System.out.printf("Index %d: %s%n", i++, item);
        }

        System.out.printf("Fixed Size Deque: %s%n", fixedDeque);

        // Convert to an array
        String[] asArray = fixedDeque.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.printf("Array: %s%n", Arrays.toString(asArray));
    }
}

Here is a delegation pattern that defers to a Deque:
package org.example.collections;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Objects;

public class FixedSizeDeque<T> implements List<T> {
    private final int maxSize;
    private final Deque<T> deque;

    public FixedSizeDeque(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        this.deque = new ArrayDeque<>(maxSize);
    }

    // Note: This is the only important method to implement
    // The rest of the methods delegate to the deque field
    @Override
    public boolean add(T item) {
        // The first item falls off the deque if it's full
        if (deque.size() == maxSize) {
            deque.removeFirst(); // Remove the oldest element
        }
        return deque.add(item); // Add the new element to the end
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return deque.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return deque.containsAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        boolean modified = false;
        for (T item : c) {
            if (add(item)) {
                modified = true;
            }
        }
        return modified;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> c) {
        if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds: " + index);
        }
        List<T> tempList = new ArrayList<>(this);
        tempList.addAll(index, c);
        if (tempList.size() > maxSize) {
            tempList = tempList.subList(tempList.size() - maxSize, tempList.size());
        }
        deque.clear();
        deque.addAll(tempList);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return deque.removeAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return deque.retainAll(c);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= deque.size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds: " + index);
        }
        return (T) deque.toArray()[index];
    }

    @Override
    public T set(int index, T element) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= deque.size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds: " + index);
        }
        List<T> tempList = new ArrayList<>(deque);
        T oldElement = tempList.set(index, element);
        deque.clear();
        deque.addAll(tempList);
        return oldElement;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, T element) {
        if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds: " + index);
        }
        List<T> tempList = new ArrayList<>(deque);
        tempList.add(index, element);
        if (tempList.size() > maxSize) {
            tempList = tempList.subList(tempList.size() - maxSize, tempList.size());
        }
        deque.clear();
        deque.addAll(tempList);
    }

    @Override
    public T remove(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= deque.size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds: " + index);
        }
        List<T> tempList = new ArrayList<>(deque);
        T removedElement = tempList.remove(index);
        deque.clear();
        deque.addAll(tempList);
        return removedElement;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        int index = 0;
        for (T item : deque) {
            if (Objects.equals(item, o)) {
                return index;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        int index = deque.size() - 1;
        ListIterator<T> iterator = new ArrayList<>(deque).listIterator(deque.size());
        while (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
            if (Objects.equals(iterator.previous(), o)) {
                return index;
            }
            index--;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
        return new ArrayList<>(deque).listIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds: " + index);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(deque).listIterator(index);
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        if (fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > size() || fromIndex > toIndex) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds: " + fromIndex + " to " + toIndex);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(deque).subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return deque.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return deque.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return deque.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return deque.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return deque.toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public <T1> T1[] toArray(T1[] a) {
        return deque.toArray(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        deque.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return deque.toString();
    }
}


AbstractList
The best way to create a new List implementation should be extending AbstractList.
class FixedSizeList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
  private final E[] elements;

  FixedSizeList() {
    this(100);
  }
  FixedSizeList(int size) {
    elements = (E[]) new Object[size];
  }

  @Override
  public E get(int index) {
    return elements[index];
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
    return elements.length;
  }

  public E set(int index, E element) {
    E previous = elements[index];
    elements[index] = element;
    return previous;
  }
}

The creation of the array gives a compiler warning; for discussion on that, see this.

You can use a custom implementation of a circular buffer. A circular buffer (also known as a ring buffer) is a data structure that uses a single, fixed-size buffer as if it were connected end-to-end.
import java.util.*;

public class FixedSizeList<E> implements List<E> {
    private final int maxSize;
    private final Object[] buffer;
    private int head;
    private int size;

    public FixedSizeList(int maxSize) {
        if (maxSize <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size must be greater than zero");
        }
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        this.buffer = new Object[maxSize];
        this.head = 0;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        head = (head - 1 + maxSize) % maxSize;
        buffer[head] = e;
        if (size < maxSize) {
            size++;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds: " + index);
        }
        int realIndex = (head + index) % maxSize;
        return (E) buffer[realIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public E remove(int index) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove operation is not supported.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove operation is not supported.");
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        Arrays.fill(buffer, null);
        head = 0;
        size = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (o.equals(get(i))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {
            private int index = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return index < size;
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                return get(index++);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        Object[] result = new Object[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            result[i] = get(i);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        if (a.length < size) {
            return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(toArray(), size, a.getClass());
        }
        System.arraycopy(toArray(), 0, a, 0, size);
        if (a.length > size) {
            a[size] = null;
        }
        return a;
    }

    // Unsupported operations
    @Override public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    @Override public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    @Override public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    @Override public E set(int index, E element) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    @Override public void add(int index, E element) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    @Override public int indexOf(Object o) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    @Override public int lastIndexOf(Object o) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    @Override public ListIterator<E> listIterator() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    @Override public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    @Override public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FixedSizeList<String> fixedList = new FixedSizeList<>(100);

        for (int i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
            fixedList.add("Item " + i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < fixedList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Index " + i + ": " + fixedList.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("Fixed Size List: " + Arrays.toString(fixedList.toArray()));
    }
}



Why doesn't FixedSizeList impement the List interface?

You can, it would just be more work.

it's really not that much code. It would be advised for completeness.

@KurtGarcia thanks for your answer, unfortunately, I am not able to use other than List Interface, is there a way or previous possible answer to continue with the List Interface

I've editted the previous answer, note that some of the List interfaces operations don't make sense for Fixed Size List, so they'll just throw exceptions when called.
